# Почему pyshark не обрабатывает все данные, а только выборочно

Tags: python, python-3.9

Pyshark берет любую рандомную строку (при использовании индекса 0) в .pcap/.pcapng/.cap и обрабатывает только ее.

Код следующий:

```
capture = pyshark.FileCapture('SIP.pcap', only_summaries=True)
for packet in capture:
  print(capture[1])
```

При попытке найти данные по индексу 1 выдает ошибку:

Packet of index 1 does not exist in capture

---

Другие пакеты даже не рассматривает...Раньше такого не было. Как это пофиксить?